# Email not working when the Approval Status column (for resource booking) changes?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar, content-approval

I not sure whether I am reasoning correctly. Below is my scenario:

User enters a new booking within Resource Booking calendar.
Admin approves / rejects.
User receives email that item has been approved / rejected.

The below are the steps I have taken:

- Created Calendar
- Within calendar settings Ticked yes for Require content approval for submitted items?
- Created workflow (2013 version) as below:

  1. The contents of this loop will run repeatedly while `Current Item:Approval Status` is not empty
  2. Log 'awaiting status' to the workflow history list
  3. If `Current Item:Approval Status` equals `0#Approved`, email User
  4. If Current Item:Approval Status equals `1#Rejected`, email User

I (as user) then tried to create an item within the calendar.
I (as admin) approved it. However user did not receive email that it has been approved.
I checked the workflow history and noticed that the loop is somehow stuck and not registering the approved so as to send the email. The workflow history keeps on showing 'awaiting status'. It seems as if its not going to the next step.

Can you assist?
How can the workflow check that the `ApprovalStatus` column has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Change the workflow to start automatically on change:
[image]

Have the workflow check if the approval status changed.  If it changed, then continue to check the value.  If not, then end the workflow.

You can also try the `Wait for Field Change in Current Item` action, however changes to the action in 2013 will require parallel actions, as described [here](http://blog.fpweb.net/sharepoint-headache-change-in-wait-for-field-change/#.VuBGFKEoEeE).